# Method Dipose of a modal form isn't called when closing it

Tags: c#, .net

I have two Forms: Form1 and Form2.
Form1 is a main Form. I create a button on Form1 to show Form2.
If I show Form2 like a modeless form (using method Show()), its Dispose method is called immediately after closing it.
But if I show Form2 like a modal form (using method ShowDialog()), its Dispose method is not called after closing it. It is only called after closing Form1 (main form) and exit application.

```
//code Dispose method of Form2
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
```

Note: I use Debug to trap in Dispose method.

How to call Dispose() immediately when closing a modal form.

Please explain it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually call `.Dispose()` in your code in Form1 right after the `.ShowDialog()`.